# How can certain warnings be ignored while others turned to exceptions from Python command line?

Tags: python, exception, warnings, command-line-arguments

How can execute Python from the command line and ignore certain warings (such as `DeprecationWarning`) while turning the rest into exceptions?

Can the `-W` option be used multiple times to do this?

The specific problem I am facing is that I am running `pytest`/`pytest-cov` inside of `tox`/`virtualenv` and because [`virtualenv` uses an outdated `site.py` module](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/555), a `DeprecationWarning` is thrown when I run with `-Werror` before I gain access in my code to catch it.  I'd like to minimize the effect to my testing by at least ignoring only this warning, and turn the others (`ImportWarning`, etc) into exceptions so I can detect and handle those in my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page does have information on this, but It's a little hard to read. I couldn't find this question until posting a question, so I'll see if I can make it easier to find:

Pitfall: `-W` options are masked by later options, `-Werror` needs to occur *before* `-Wignore`

---

Filter by exception:

```
python -werror -Wignore::PendingDeprecationWarning your_stuff.py
```

---

Filter by line:

```
python -Werror -Wignore::::32 your_stuff.py
```

For ignoring a warning on line 32

---

Filter by module/file:

```
python -Werror -Wignore:::site: your_stuff.py
```

To ignore any warning from the `site.py` module in your example(the last file in the exception traceback)

---

The options are `action:message:category:module:line`

---

Man page:

```
   -W argument
          Warning control.  Python sometimes prints warning message to sys.stderr.  A typical warning  message
          has  the following form: file:line: category: message.  By default, each warning is printed once for
          each source line where it occurs.  This option controls how often warnings are printed.  Multiple -W
          options  may be given; when a warning matches more than one option, the action for the last matching
          option is performed.  Invalid -W options are ignored (a warning message  is  printed  about  invalid
          options  when  the  first  warning is issued).  Warnings can also be controlled from within a Python
          program using the warnings module.

          The simplest form of argument is one of the following action strings  (or  a  unique  abbreviation):
          ignore  to  ignore  all  warnings; default to explicitly request the default behavior (printing each
          warning once per source line); all to print a warning each time it occurs (this  may  generate  many
          messages if a warning is triggered repeatedly for the same source line, such as inside a loop); modâ€
          ule to print each warning only the first time it occurs in each module; once to print  each  warning
          only  the  first time it occurs in the program; or error to raise an exception instead of printing a
          warning message.

          The full form of argument is action:message:category:module:line.   Here,  action  is  as  explained
          above  but only applies to messages that match the remaining fields.  Empty fields match all values;
          trailing empty fields may be omitted.  The message field matches the start of  the  warning  message
          printed;  this  match  is  case-insensitive.  The category field matches the warning category.  This
          must be a class name; the match test whether the actual warning category of the message  is  a  subâ€
          class  of  the  specified  warning  category.   The full class name must be given.  The module field
          matches the (fully-qualified) module name; this match is case-sensitive.  The line field matches the
          line number, where zero matches all line numbers and is thus equivalent to an omitted line number.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
python -Werror -Wignore::DeprecationWarning your_stuff.py
```

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W

Comment: Perfect, the double `::` was what I was missing, didn't read the docs quite right.